# "True or -1 > None" returns True

Tags: python, nonetype

In Python, `True or -1 > None` returns `True` but `True > None` and `-1 > None` returns `False`???

Why is this?

Comment: You can't do `a or b > c` to check if either `a` or `b` is greater than `c`. The first code snippet is evaluated as `(True) or (-1 > None)` and since `True` is true, the expression is also true.

Comment: You are using Python 2. This is a bad idea. Such comparisons work differently in Python 3 which you probably should be using.

Comment: `True > None` and `-1 > None` both return `True` in `2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `True or -1 > None` evaluates as `True or (-1 > None)`, which is always True, regardless of the expression